# Where do I get 18650? e scooter battery pack

Tags: batteries

There is some chinese 18650
http://www.aliexpress.com/item/4pc-a-lot-Free-shippng-18650-Li-ion-Rechargeable-3-7V-9800mAh-Battery-for-Flashlight-Newest/32518061115.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.8.WalUmo

What is the catch here?

10pc a lot Free shippng 18650 Li-ion Rechargeable 3.7V 9800mAh Battery for Flashlight Newest 18650 battery $12

I would only need 15 to make a 48v 10ah battery pack?

Am I missing something here because I could sell these?

researching e scooter battery pack

some links would be nice

sla's don't work on these not if you weigh 190lb
[a busy cat http://motorcycle.brick7-ca.com/media/ca/1417401_1417500/1417464_81747c176ef702cb.jpg](http://motorcycle.brick7-ca.com/media/ca/1417401_1417500/1417464_81747c176ef702cb.jpg)

Comment: If you believe that capacity in that size .... well, check the feedback very carefully before you buy.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Looking at the feedback there, I think this comic applies: https://xkcd.com/937/ -- Though I did like the american giving it a 5 star with "BETTER QUALITY AVAILABLE". Made my day.

Comment: Most of the cheap 18650s on eBay are crap, with a fraction of the advertised capacity: http://www.ebay.com/gds/18650-Battery-Buying-Guide-test-on-all-from-eBay-below-3-/10000000178020340/g.html

Comment: @Asmyldof I thought you were aiming for this one... https://xkcd.com/325/

Answer (score 2):

Even the most respected manufacturers of 18650 cells (LG, Samsung, Sony, Panasonic, Sanyo) **do not** produce cells with such a high capacity. Their best cells are aroud 3500 mAh max.

So cells that are **supposedly** 9800 mAh tell me that these cells will be **CRAP**. I guarantee you that these will have **far less** usable capacity than 9800 mAh. You might be lucky if they can store 2000 mAh.

Besides that, dealing with Li-Ion based cells is **not for the clueless**. You need to have a good understanding of how to treat them. If you don't then don't tell you I did not warn you after your battery **explodes/starts smoking/catches fire/lasts only 2 minutes**.

One last point: why do you think e scooters / e-bikes / electric cars are expensive ? Let me tell you: it's the batteries. Good batteries are expensive. Don't waste your money on cheap brandless batteries with no guarantee that they work. Manufacturers (of e scooters etc.) know that so they buy **quality batteries**, they are worth it.

Comment: Yep. I'd leave the Li-ion cells for the better-armored cars and stick to LiFePO4 for scooters/e-bikes.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the catch here?

Three big ones. First, you have no guarantee that what you'll get is actually 9800 mAH, and if you get cheated you have no practical recourse.

Second, although 15 cells will indeed give you 48 volts, charging a 15-cell stack will be much harder than you think. You must handle each cell individually for best results, and that is much more circuitry than you are probably ready for. Also, it will be important to monitor the stack while operating, since if you exhaust the weakest cell in the stack it will then begin operating reverse-biased, and this will kill a cell in fairly short order.

Finally, there is no guarantee that the cells will produce the current you need. Don't count on high current capability, and a scooter definitely counts as a high-current requirement.

Comment: In fact, looking at the LiIon Chemistry and maximum energy density, with respect to the volume of a 18650 the maximum current high-end fabrication can reach is 3460-ish mAh. It can be hyped up to about 3800mAh for marketing purposes, but that's newest tech, mind you. I'm willing to guarantee less than 1Ah per cell for those.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, this explains a lot.  Also I am not clueless I am very far from even starting to build this fiery mess.